# Azure B2C custom policy for disabling accounts returns 401 for all api requests

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have been following the code provided by MS for creating a custom policy that will disable inactive accounts after a specified period of time: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-inactive-account. I have also done all the steps to enable using custom policy, particularly with the help of this site: [b2c setup](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/). I have created a repo where I have uploaded all our custom policy files and a json file with an example app insights trace: https://github.com/rich-staackmann/azure-b2c-issue.

The current issue is that every time I login, the html loads but all requests to the backend api return a 401. I tried a few different changes to the policy but nothing seems to matter. The only thing I can think of is that this app has a weird app registration setup. It's a SPA with a API backend. However, the team setup a single app registration for everything. Instead of a registration for the SPA and another for the API. Could that have this effect?

Answer (score 0):

So after much debugging it turns out that the answer was simple. When we updated the frontend code to use the new custom policy we forgot to update the backend as well. This leads to some sort of mismatch and you can see in the JWT token that the name of the custom policy is a part of the token. Once we updated both places, the issue was resolved.